# Why do some YouTube "Subscribe" buttons show numbers and some do not?

Tags: youtube

Can I make them always show the numbers?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is based on a privacy setting, you set. Here’s how you can change it.

You can choose to make the channels that you subscribe to public or private. By default, all settings are set to private.

- Private: When your subscriptions are set to private, no other users can see what channels you subscribe to. Your account does not show in a channel's Subscribers List, even if you are subscribed.
- Public: When your subscriptions are set to public, other users can see what channels you subscribe to. Your subscriptions are listed on your channel page, and your account is listed in the Subscribers List for any channel you subscribe to.

Make your channel subscriptions public or private

- Sign in to YouTube.
- Click your account icon in the top right.
- Click Settings or The ⚙️ Icon
- In the left menu, select Privacy.
- Under "Likes and subscriptions," check or uncheck the box for Keep all my subscriptions private. Or if you want it public, check to make them public.

Comment: So, basically it is because the owner of the channel set his or her setting to private? I was not talking about my channel; I was talking about the channels of which I cannot know its number of subscribers. Then, there seems to be nothing I can do for it.

Comment: Yes That is Correct